# Custom event migration from source code to GTM in GA3

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Currently, I have custom events implemented in source code and I would like to migrate them on GTM. Is there any option to migrate all those custom events rather than doing it manually (implement all custom events in GTM again from scratch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's definitely no such option due to how many ways custom events can be implemented.

They should be carefully migrated manually. Preferably by someone with solid front-end experience or in collaboration with FE developers.

Comment: Thank you very much.